# Preconditioning of a linear system

Tags: sparse-matrix, numeric, numerical-methods, numerical, pde

I have a large sparse linear system generated as a part of PDE solution for flows in the form `Ax=b`. The condition number of matrix A is very bad - of the order 3000!. But I get expected solutions with direct solvers. So, now I want to precondition the matrix so that I can use iterative solvers and use the sparseness. I have tried Jacobi preconditioner, but it does not work well as the matrix is not diagonally dominant. I need some help in proceeding further:

1) Imagine I get an approximate solution for `x` (generated by one run of biconjugate gradient solver). Now can I get "inverse of A" (for preconditioning) from this, seems like it must be possible but I am unable to figure out how! i.e knowing `x` and `b` can I calculate the `A inverse` (which may be used as preconditioner!).

2) Any other way of preconditioning which you feel would be worth a try?

3) Any way to circumvent pre-conditioning for iterative schemes for bad condition number systems?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help. Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Finding inverse of A is not a good idea if you try to solve a large sparse linear system. Why do you try to use sparse direct matrix solver (i.e. SuiteSparse, SuperLU).

Comment: You could use reordering techniques to adjust matrix into few blocks which may have better condition numbers.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I will try the above mentioned libraries for any future related work.